# How to show user's context resourcelist only

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

MODX Revolution 2.2.10-pl
Migx 2.6.8

I use this in a TV for my clients to be abble to choose a ressource :

```
{"field":"link1","caption":"Lien","inputTVtype":"resourcelist"}
```

The context of a user is defined with a user group context access. 
I've tried to tick the checkbox of the user usergroup in the TV, but if I do that the user is not abble to see th TV anymore.

Problem is that mys client can see every ressources of every contexts. I need him to only be abble to see the resourcelist of their context. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a TV with custom @eval options and use that for your migx field. See here for an example and description; http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/template-variables/bindings/eval-binding.

First change your TV to this, basically just swapping out "inputTVtype" to "inputTV"

```
{
    "field":"link1",
    "caption":"Lien",
    "inputTV":"yourCustomTv"
}
```

Step two is to create a snippet that finds the resources you want, this requires you to have some knowledge of PHP. Basically you need to find the resources and loop them, outputting a string that looks like a regular list values string (`resourceId==name||resourceId==name||...`)

Step three is to create "yourCustomTv", and for the input options give it the `@EVAL return $modx->runSnippet('yourSnippet');`

Comment: It's even simplier when you create a ressource list TV you can limit it to the current context. Thank you !